# Перемещение файлов java

Tags: файлы, java

Добрый вечер. 3 дня уже пытаюсь понять, как перемещать файлы в java. Есть задача: прочитать список файлов из указанного каталога, отсортировать по слову, вводимому с клавиатуры и переместить отсортированные файлы в указанный каталог.
Этот метод возвращает список файлов из каталога.

```
 public static String[] getFilesList(File fl) {

        String[] listFiles = fl.list();

        for (int i = 0; i < listFiles.length; i++) {
        }
        return listFiles;
    }
```

Далее реализована сортировка циклом:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i].indexOf(inpFilterName) > 0)
```

И вот теперь самая большая проблема - в этом же цикле я хочу сразу перемещать файлы по указанному пути. Гугл подсказал, что необходимо использовать метод renameTo() класса File. Пыталась реализовать так:

```
 File dir = new File();
 dir.renameTo()
```

Но я не могу понять, что передавать ему в качестве аргументов, и сработает ли, если на входе у нас имя файла а не файл?
 Вобщем, я совсем запуталась и очень жду помощи!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Рискну предположить, что под сортировкой вы имели ввиду фильтрацию - т.е. переместить только те файлы, в именах которых содержится указанная строка `inpFilterName`. В таком случае можно поступить следующим образом:

```
File destFolder = new File("output"); // это папка, в которую будем перемещать
File[] files = fl.listFiles(); // получаем непосредственно файлы, не просто имена
for (File file : files) {
    if (file.getName().indexOf(inpFilterName) != -1) {
        file.renameTo(new File(destFolder, file.getName()));
    }
}
```

Кстати, обратите внимание на разницу условий в `if`. Возможно, вы написали ровно то, что хотели, но на всякий случай: ваше условие выберет строки, в которых искомая подстрока стоит по индексу 1 или больше. Т.е. "test123".indexOf("test") это условие не пропустит. `String#indexOf()`  возвращает -1 в случае неудачи, а не 0.

Comment: >Т.е. "test123".indexOf("test") это условие не пропустит

Пропускает. У меня в условии стоит > 0, т.е. не -1. За пример реализации спасибо, я думала по поводу него. Один вопрос: Получаем непосредственно файлы! Эту программу я нацелена использовать для сортировки мр3. Какие будут последствия и что станет с производительностью, если в массив будет помещаться пара десятков мр3 файлов? Можно, конечно, для сортировки сначала использовать список имен, и  из него делать выборку.. а уж потом перемещать.. Я не совсем понимаю, как это будет выглядеть.

Comment: Прошу прощения, документация все разъяснила

Returns an array of abstract pathnames denoting the files and directories in the directory denoted by this abstract pathname that satisfy the specified filter.

Comment: Все отлично работает! Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

**Проверь этот код!** 
Я сам писал. 
В этом коде сначала renameTo - перемещает папку в другой каталог и потом отсортирует, то есть удаляет ненужные файлы из папки после перемещения.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class File_remove {

    private static String to = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String from = "c:/from";
        to = "c:/to";

        File From = new File(from);
        if (!From.exists()) {
            System.out.println(to + " does not exist!");
            return;
        }

        File To = new File(to);
        if (!To.delete()){
            System.out.println("You can't move!");
            return;
        }

        From.renameTo(To);

        Check(To.list(), "inputFilterName");
    }

    public static void Check(String[] arr, String inpFilterName) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i].indexOf(inpFilterName) < 0){
                    if (!(new File(to + File.separator + arr[i]).delete())){
                        System.out.println("You can't delete the file!");
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: за старания 5, а за код 2. учимся правильно называть классы, переменные, методы